# How to determine convergence of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have no problem showing that this is indeed convergent, as it is obviously Cauchy. I am having difficulty showing what it converges to.

> Let $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ be any two real numbers, and define $$
> a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2} $$ Determine the convergence of the
>   sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$

I searched but could not find this previously asked. Now in the sidebar I see that this is a duplicate.

[Determine the convergence of a sequence given by $a_n= \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699640/determine-the-convergence-of-a-sequence-given-by-a-n-fraca-n-1-a-n-22?rq=1)

[Limit of sequence in which each term is defined by the average of preceding two terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276402/limit-of-sequence-in-which-each-term-is-defined-by-the-average-of-preceding-two)

Comment: Isn't $\frac{a_0+2a_1}{3}$?

Comment: Looked and those answers seem complicated and overkill-i would think in terms of weighted averages as $a_1$ obviously weighs twice as $a_0$